# How to access files within a JAX-RS web service directory by specifying their URL?

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

Given a JAX-RS web service deployed under Tomcat, how can I make some of the files accessible directly from the browser by specifying the URL like `http://site/path/file`?

Let's say I have web service method returning an HTML web page and I need, within that page, to load a CSS file or an image file stored in the web service directory. For example:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public synchronized String root() {
    String head = "<head><link href=\"path/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></head>";
    String head = "<body><img src=\"path/image.jpg\"/></body>";
    return "<html>"+ head + body + "<html>";
}
```

Where should I put the file within the web service directories (`WebContent`, `META-INF`, `WEB-INF`, etc) and what path should I put in the html page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have three choices: [absolute, relative or root links](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php).

Absolute links work if you have your files as external resources. Relative URLs are most of the time a pain for static resources like styles, scripts or images because they must be resolved starting from the location that refers to them (they can be in various forms like `images/image.jpg, ../image.jpg, ../images/image.jpg` etc).

So a preferred way is to have styles, scripts or images at known positions within your application and access it with root links (slash prefixed URLs) like `/Images/image.jpg`.

Your folders must be in the folder of the application (`WebContent` in your question). Placing something under WEB-INF hides the resource and clients can no longer access it.

These links resolve to the root of your application so you must account for the context path. A basic example would be something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("whatever_path_might_be")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML
public String root(@Context ServletContext ctx) {
    String ctxPath = ctx.getContextPath();
    String stylesFolder = ctxPath + "/Styles";
    String imagesFolder = ctxPath + "/Images";

    String head = "<head><link href=\"" + stylesFolder + "/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></head>";
    String body = "<body><img src=\"" + imagesFolder + "/image.jpg\"/></body>";
    return "<html>"+ head + body + "<html>";
}
```

This is a basic example, I'm sure you can find ways to improve it. You could event have these paths in a .properties file and loaded as general configuration. This will later allow you to switch from something like:

```
resources.cssFolder=/appcontext/styles
resources.imgFolder=/appcontext/images
```

to something like:

```
resources.cssFolder=http://external.server.com/styles
resources.imgFolder=http://external.server.com/images
```

without changing a line of code.

Comment: I've tried both with `getContextPath` and `getRealPath("image.jpg")` but it doesn't seem to work. I am testing it locally on _Ubuntu 12.10_ with _Tomcat 7_ running under _Eclipse_. The files are indeed in the file system in the right location under `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService`. Inspected elements on the browser give `404 Not Found`. The Tomcat server log in `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/logs/` says `127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2013:11:02:44 +0100] "GET /MyWebService/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 967`.

Comment: I've done some tests and it looks like if I move the files from `.../wtpwebapps/MyWebService` to `.../wtpwebapps/ROOT` everything works fine, without the context path as URLs prefix.

Comment: @Krige: have you placed the files in the `...org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWe‌​bService` folder by hand or did you add them to your Java project in Eclipse and then deployed?

Comment: I have set up Tomcat to run as server inside Eclipse. I work on the files in my Eclipse project, on every change they get automatically deployed into wtpwebapps and Tomcat is restarted.

Comment: @Krige: If the files are deployed to the right path and the links are correct, then there is no reason not to work. Make sure the paths are case sensitive (e.g. `/MyWebService/image.jpg` is not the same as `/MyWebService/Image.jpg`). You can debug the issue by directly entering the paths in the browser (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/image.jpg` assuming that's where you placed your image file).

Comment: I have made the test you suggested and in the browser I get a _HTTP Status 404 - Not Found, type Status report, message Not Found, description. The requested resource is not available_, while Tomcat logs _GET /MyWebService/image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 967_. I am guessing something is wrong with my `web.xml` [link](http://pastebin.com/uAMjPxGq)

Comment: If I manually copy the file into `../wtpwebapps/ROOT` then I can see the image in the browser using the URL `http://localhost:8080/image.jpg`

Comment: It was indeed my `web.xml` fault: I changed the **url-pattern** from `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/MyWebService</url-pattern>` and now everything works fine.